# AngularJs databinding from factory

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJs, and I've got a little problem without using $scope in my factory module.

I've got a GET function that's used by a controller via the factory, and it's supposed to return a list from my db as json
and show it on the html using ng-repeat. For a reason I couldn't find a solution for, it doesn't. My only guess was that there's a problem regarding databinding from the factory to the html.

How do I bind the returned json to a variable and bind that variable to my html?

This function worked before I created the factory, but without using the $scope
I'm pretty lost. 
I hope I was able to explain myself correctly.

Factory:

```
   (function() {

    angular.module("myApp").factory('appServicesProvider',function( $http ) {

    var restURL = "http://localhost:8080/Project/rest/api/";


   function getAllRows(allRows){

    $http.get(restURL).then(
            function(response){
                allRows = response.data.coupon;
            } 
    );
}

return{getAllRows:getAllRows}
```

Controller:

```
    (function() {

    angular.module("myApp")
    .controller("AdminController",function($scope, $http, 
     appServicesProvider) {


     // I know that this method  of scoping a service is not best and/or recommended, 
     //it just works better for me with the admin controller.
    $scope.appServicesProvider = appServicesProvider;
```

HTML:

```
   <div id="getAllRowsDiv">

        <table class="table table-hover">
         <thead>
           <tr>
               // list details

           <th></th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
           <tr ng-repeat="coupon in allRows">

            // list

           </tr>
         </tbody>
   </table>
    <button  class="btn  btn-success" ng-
     click="appServicesProvider.getAllRows()"  >Get All Rows</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $q

```
(function() {

    angular.module("myApp").factory('appServicesProvider',function( $q, $http ) {

    var restURL = "http://localhost:8080/Project/rest/api/";


   function getAllRows(allRows){
    var deffer = $q.defer();
    $http.get(restURL).then(
            function(response){
                deffer.resolve(response.data.coupon;)
            },function(error){
                deffer.reject(error)
             } 
    );
    return deffer.promise

}

return{getAllRows:getAllRows}
```

and in controller

```
$scope.getRows = function(){
     appServicesProvider.getAllRows().then(function(res){
           $scope.allRows = res;
         },function(err){
           alert(err)
         })
 }
 $scope.getRows();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but that seems a little bit confusing. How/where does the object binds to the html var 'allRows'?

Comment: I have edited the code, please check in the controller code.

Comment: Alright, that worked, but now it executes the function automatically without me calling it, is there a way to manage that?

Comment: Write that code inside a function and call it manually when you want to execute the code. Check my edit. :)

Comment: @georgeawg, yes there is no need to use $q here and $http itself returns promise, but using $q you can validate what to be returned to the controller and what to be rejected.

Comment: @Rishi [Read You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/). Use a [return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) or a [throw statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) in the `.then` or `.catch` handlers to modify what is returned or rejected to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

In the service, return the http promise:

```
app.factory('appServices',function( $http ) {

    return { getAllRows:getAllRows }

    var restURL = "http://localhost:8080/Project/rest/api/";

    function getAllRows(){        
        ͟r͟e͟t͟u͟r͟n͟ $http.get(restURL)
          .then(function(response){
            var allRows = response.data.coupon;
            ͟r͟e͟t͟u͟r͟n͟  allRows; 
        });
    }
});
```

In the controller, use the `.then` method to extract the data:

```
app.controller("AdminController",function($scope, $http, appServices) {

    var promise = appServices.getAllRows();

    promise.then(function(allRows) {
        $scope.allRows = appRows;
    });
});
```